# Highlight a cell that is greater than or equal a value when another cell is a specific text

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am creating a tracker,

- In cell A1 I want to define the value with a 1, 2,or 3.
- In Cell B1 I want to highlight if the Cell Value >=60 when A1 is a 1,
- and In Cell B1 I want to highlight if the Cell Value >=45 when A1 is a 2.

How do I get excel to identify if A1 is a 1 or 2 and then apply the conditional format that correlates to that number **(>=60 if it is a 1 and =>45 if it is a 2)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formatting rule:

```
=OR(AND($A$1=1,$B$1>=60),AND($A$1=2,$B$1>=45))
```

[image]

If you intend for this to apply to other rows, then be sure to adjust the $ anchors appropriately and set the 'Applies to' range as needed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you don't need to do it all at once with a single formula.  It is often easier to create sequential rules in the conditional formatting dialog.  it may be easiest to create multiple rules so that the formula for each rule is simplified and more understandable later:

Rule 1 formula:

```
=AND($A1=1,$B1>=60)
```

Rule 2 formula:

```
=AND($A1=2,$B1>=45)
```

Be mindful of the locations of the $ signs that must be on the column letters but must not be on the row numbers.

You absolutely can combine this into one formula if you'd like:

```
=OR( AND($A1=1,$B1>=60) , AND($A1=2,$B1>=45) )
```

**Edit for clarity**
I see FlexYourData and I were typing the exact same solution at the same time.  Their answer presents an important distinction about whether ONLY A1 and B1 are used to apply formatting for the whole sheet (their assumption), or whether *EACH ROW'S* A and B are used to determine the highlighting for that row (my assumption).